# Proof verification for the convergence of an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

**Proposition:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that satisfies the following conditions:

(a) Is strictly decreasing on the interval $[n_0,\infty)$, with $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$, and $f(n_0) = h$.

(b) Has limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$.

(c) Is integrable.

Then:

(1) The following limit exists and it is finite:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} f(\lfloor t\rfloor)\ dt - \int_{n_0}^x f(t)\ dt =: I_0$$

(2) The following limit exists and it is finite:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{n_0}^x f(\lfloor t\rfloor) - f(t)\ dt =: I_1$$

(3) The following identities hold:

$$0 \leq I_0 = I_1 \leq h.$$

---

*My proof attempt:*

Note that since $f$ is strictly decreasing and has limit $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity, then it is positive and bounded for $x\in [n_0,\infty)$. Moreover, $f(\lfloor x\rfloor) \geq f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where the equality is attained precisely for integer values of $x$.
Let $a_n = \int_{n}^{n+1} f(n) - f(t)\ dt$. Then $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n_0 \leq n\in\mathbb{N}$.

(1) We have
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor} f(\lfloor t\rfloor)\ dt - \int_{n_0}^x f(t)\ dt
&= \lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{n = n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} \int_{n}^{n+1} f(n) - f(t)\ dt  - \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x f(t)\ dt\\
&= \lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{n = n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} a_n - \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x f(t)\ dt
\end{align}$$

Now, $0 \leq \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x f(t)\ dt \leq \{x\}f(\lfloor x\rfloor) \leq f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$, so $0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x f(t)\ dt \leq  \lim_{x\to\infty} f(\lfloor x\rfloor) = 0$. This means that our limit is just
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{n = n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} a_n.$$

Note that $0 \leq a_n = \int_{n}^{n+1} f(n) - f(t)\ dt \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} f(n) - f(n+1)\ dt = f(n) - f(n+1)$. Let $b_n = f(n) - f(n+1)$. Then $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$. The partial sums of the series of $a_n$ is strictly increasing and it is bounded by the partial series of $b_n$.

Let us prove that the series of $b_n$ converges:

$\sum_{n = n_0}^N b_n = \sum_{n = n_0}^N f(n) - f(n+1) = f(n_0) - f(N+1)$. Since $\lim_{N\to\infty} f(N+1) = 0$ then $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty b_n= f(n_0) = h$. This means that the series of $a_n$ is strictly increasing and bounded above, i.e., it converges. This concludes the proof of (1).

(2) We have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{n_0}^x f(\lfloor t\rfloor) - f(t)\ dt = \sum_{n= n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} a_n + \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x f(\lfloor x\rfloor) - f(t) \ dt.$$
Now, $0\leq \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x f(\lfloor x\rfloor) - f(t) \ dt \leq \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x f(\lfloor x\rfloor) - f(x) \ dt = \{x\}(f(\lfloor x\rfloor) - f(x))$ but the limit as $x\to\infty$ of both $f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ and $f(x)$ is $0$, so our limit is just
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_{n = n_0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1} a_n.$$
Which we already proved it converges. This concludes the proof of (2).

(3) Both limits are trivially non-negative. We already proved that they are both equal to $\sum_{n = n_0}^{\infty} a_n$, which is bounded above by $\sum_{n = n_0} b_n = h$. This concludes the proof of (3).

Comment: Always love it when they enumerate properties, but toss an additional one ("positive") in the introduction before starting their enumeration. Also love it when their properties are obviously redundant: (a) and (c) $\implies$ "positive" and (b).

Comment: I see no issues with your proof.